# Rails 5 custom validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I am learning Rails and I stuck with this custom validation. I tried many different approaches to pass the form field called `(:cpf)` to validate without success. I also tried using ActiveModel::EachValidator, but I get more confused. The validation is a check digit using modulo 11. So this is what I ended up.

**controllers/drivers_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @driver = Driver.new
  end

  def create
    @driver = Driver.new(driver_params)
    if @driver.save
      flash[:success] = "Motorista cadastrado com sucesso!"
      redirect_to @driver
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**models/driver.rb**

```
class Driver < ApplicationRecord

validate :checkcpf

private

  def checkcpf
    return false if cpf.nil?
    nulos = %w{12345678909 11111111111 22222222222 33333333333 44444444444 55555555555 66666666666 77777777777 88888888888 99999999999 00000000000}
    valor = cpf.scan /[0-9]/
    if valor.length == 11
      unless nulos.member?(valor.join)
        valor = valor.collect{|x| x.to_i}
        soma = 10*valor[0]+9*valor[1]+8*valor[2]+7*valor[3]+6*valor[4]+5*valor[5]+4*valor[6]+3*valor[7]+2*valor[8]
        soma = soma - (11 * (soma/11))
        resultado1 = (soma == 0 or soma == 1) ? 0 : 11 - soma
        if resultado1 == valor[9]
          soma = valor[0]*11+valor[1]*10+valor[2]*9+valor[3]*8+valor[4]*7+valor[5]*6+valor[6]*5+valor[7]*4+valor[8]*3+valor[9]*2
          soma = soma - (11 * (soma/11))
          resultado2 = (soma == 0 or soma == 1) ? 0 : 11 - soma
          return true if resultado2 == valor[10] # CPF VALIDO
        end
      end
    end
    return false # CPF INVALIDO
    errors.add(:cpf, "CPF INVÁLIDO")
  end
end
```

I think I am missing how to pass my cpf field to validate. Either I got a error message or miss the validation.

I will try to use ActiveModel::EachValidator later when I get better understanding from Rails. This is how I usually do, try to get things to work the way I can understand then refactor the Rails way.

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no need to return either `true` or `false` from this method, just `return` - you want to either return from the method because the field is valid or add an error. I didn't quite follow the logic of your validation, but regardless of the result you always `return false # CPF INVALIDO` and the line `errors.add(:cpf, "CPF INVÁLIDO")` is never reached. Bear in mind - whenever you `return` from a method, you stop the execution, so you have to be sure that there is at least one execution path, that can reach the line, which adds the actual error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe I will create a module to test this method and try to validate if its true or false...